# Why am I getting an error if I am trying to modify data type?

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I am facing an error when I passed the following syntax in MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE store MODIFY (DOB char(40)) ;
```

I am attaching a screenshot too because then you can see that the column DOB is having all rows `NULL` in it. Even after that Data type isn't changing.

[image]

See in yellow is my syntax. Earlier, DOB was an integer. See all the rows are `NULL`. Then why the error!
Please, help even if you feel it is a silly question. I am just a school going kid who has this MySQL as my subject and I don't have any tutor too.

Comment: Did you try without parentheses? Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356866/how-do-i-change-the-data-type-for-a-column-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

In your image you have far to many parenthesis

```
ALTER TABLE store MODIFY DOB char(40);
```

The parenthesis you put around column name and type is not valid.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked.